# ¿Cómo solucionar Salida NaN en recursión?

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión

Trato de calcular por medio de recursion bases con exponentes negativos. Pero en al ser mayores que -1 la salida mostrada es nan, tal como si fuera un valor indefinido. No encuentro el error.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    double exp(double c, double n);
    int main(){
        double c, n;
        cout<<"Base"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        cout<<"Exponent"<<endl;
        cin>>n;

        cout<<"Output: "<<exp(c,n)<<endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    double exp(double c, double n){
        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        else if(-n==1)
            return 1.0/c;
        else if(n>1)
            c=c*exp(c,-n-1);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La salida mostrada es nan, tal como si fuera un valor indefinido.

No, `NaN` no es un valor indefinido, es un valor definido que significa "No es un Número" (`N`ot `a` `N`umber).

`NaN` suele ser el resultado de operaciones matemáticas que no tienen una respuesta numérica (como la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo), pero en tu caso recibes `NaN` por [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

Tal y como ha comentado [CarlosHD](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/294483/2742) tu función tiene un punto de salida en que no devuelve valor alguno y tu programa está saliendo por ahí. Utilizar el valor devuelto por una función sin que dicha función lo haya devuelto es comportamiento indefinido.

Intenta esta otra implementación:

```
double exp(double base, double exponente)
{
    if (exponente == 0)
        return 1;

    return exp(base, ++exponente) / base;
}
```

Comment: Esta implementacion funciona excelente... Aun quedo con la duda de si se puede trabajar con una implementacion donde no se retorne el valor de la base hasta que se haya acumulado esta.
 Tal como:

`int expt(int base, int exponente){
 if(exponente==0)
  return 1;
  
 else if(exponente==1)
  return base;
  
 else if(exponente>1)
  c*=expt(c, n-1);
}`

Comment: No entiendo tu duda @Frank :(

Comment: Ese fragmento de código que puse en el comentario anterior si funciona, y sería la implementación que digo (de ir acumulando c*=llamarfuncion) pero solo funciona si el retorno es de tipo int. La diferencia entre la implementación que sugiere y está de la que hablo reside en ’if(exponente==1) return base; else if(exponente>1) c*=expt(c, n-1);‘

Comment: Le pregunta sería, ¿porque no funciona con un retorno tipo double?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que si pasas -2, -3, o un número menor, al correr tu función `exp`, el programa no entra en ninguno de los casos.

Por ejemplo, si el exponente es -2, entonces `n` es -2, y `n==0` falla porque `-2==0` es falso, `-n==1` falla porque `2==1` es falso, y `n>1` falla porque `-2>1` también es falso.
Esto significa que tu función no tiene un valor de retorno para todos los valores posibles, y supongo que el compilador te manda basura. Me parece raro que no sea simplemente un error de compilación.

Y en cuanto a tu lógica, creo que como quieres hacer la llamada recursiva cuando el valor de `n` sea menor que -1 (*-2 es menor que -1*), entonces tu tercer `if` debería ser `if(n < -1)`. Y como la siguiente llamada recursiva debería sumar 1 a n (si es -2, el siguiente valor debería ser -1), entonces creo que deberías llamar `exp(c,n+1)`. Y creo que deberías dividir el resultado entre `c`, no multiplicarlo. Quedaría: `c=exp(c,n+1)/c`;
Y lo más importante, después de todo eso, al final de la función deberías regresar c: `return c;`

Comment: Gracias... Arregle los errores del codigo que comenta... Pero en si, la logica que estaba implementando, del querer acumular el valor de la base sin retornar nada llega a dar un resultado no definido aun con las modificaciones que sugiere.